# Android Services with Intent Services real time examples

Tags: android, service

I am getting confused between service and Intend service,what is the difference between service and Intend service,then on which kinds of situations we have to use service,Intend service any can explain with some real time example?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Service is a piece of code that will run on your main UI thread and will remain running until stopped, even if you aren't in the foreground.

An IntentService is a special kind of Service that starts its own Thread and queues incoming start calls to run on that thread one at a time, in the order they came in.

Use Service if you need a place for long running actions to occur that need to continue even if the Activity is killed.  For example, tracking location via GPS for a maps app.  Use IntentService for repetative pieces of work.  For example, downloading files.  Or syncing a database.  You can think of IntentService as kind of like an AsyncTask that runs in a Service.

Comment: Thank You very much sir,

Comment: i have one more doubt sir,What is difference between worker thread and background thread android some examples.

Comment: There is none. Different names for the same thing